# Radio button creation from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Radio buttons are not working properly.In first part a dropdown list is created from controller and on change of dropdown item a list is returned in $.json, i want to show each list item as a radio button label.Following is my code

```
 <div class="col9 last">
        @Html.DropDownList("PaymentModelddl", new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text"))
    </div
<div class="col9 right last" id="PlanNames">

            </div>



<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PaymentModelddl').change(function () {

        var ModelValue = $(this).val();
        //alert(ModelValue+"");
        if (ModelValue > 0) {
            $.getJSON('/AccountInfoTemp/TestJSON/' + ModelValue, function (result) {
                var ddl = $('#PlanNames');
                ddl.empty();
                var d = "";
                $(result).each(function () {
                    d += "<input type='radio' name='radio' style='display:block; float:left;' />"
                        + "<span class='label'>" + this.Name + "</span><div class='clear'></div>";
                });

                d += ""
                ddl.html(d);
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `$.each()`:

```
$.each(result, function(idx, item) {
    d += "<input type='radio' name='radio' style='display:block; float:left;' />"
      + "<span class='label'>" + item.Name + "</span><div class='clear'></div>";
});
```